# Use one "main project" as source for many projects: how to do it best with GitHub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, fork, project-management

I'm planning 3-4 Rails projects. All of them share some basic functionalities, and I want to use the same development tools (e.g. RSpec) for all of them. But I don't feel like configuring every project completely from the ground up.

So I'm thinking of starting with one "base project" in which I configure all needed tools, and then to create a fork of it for all of the "real" projects. Everything all projects share is developed within "base project" and then synced into the forks.

Is this a good idea? I know that there are other possibilities to share common code (like gems or even gemified engines), but for a fast start I think my idea is quite effective.

Anyone has done this before? With good or rather bad results?

Any other ideas or hints are highly appreciated.

**Update**

Damn it, I just found out that I can't fork a repository into its own repository. Hm, I think there's a reason why people don't seem to do this. But simply copy&paste a project doesn't seem useful to me, as I also want to get stuff from a "real project" back into the "base project" when I think that it's useful for all other projects, too. I could do that with creating patches and stuff, but this seems rather cumbersome.

**Update**

I found a quite easy way to fork own projects in the same repository: http://bitdrift.com/post/4534738938/fork-your-own-project-on-github

Look at the comments though, there the easiest method is described.

Comment: Look at Git submodules and subtrees and see if they address your issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Templates**

You should look at using [`templates`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) -

an inbuilt Rails feature which allows you to define certain attributes of a project (gems etc), and then "inherit" them in other projects

I've never used them myself, so I can't provide any code right now, but the tutorial seems pretty good :)

Comment: This is indeed an interesting feature, thanks for pointing me to it. For the time being, it is too complex/limited, though, as I want my new projects to have really a lot of stuff already preconfigured, including some standard feature specs (registration, logging in/out, etc.).

Comment: As with the standard Rails documentation, it's quite limited in scope as to what you can do with it. I've seen very in depth integrations of this mentioned on SO, so you may be better seeking further info on it in order to gain a more informed decision :)

Comment: I definitely will do this some time. But for the moment, I'm more interested in feedback about my idea about forking a main project. :)

Comment: No problem! It will be interesting to find out how to do it!!